# How to fix undefined is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.apps.length')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "removed",
    authDomain: "removed",
    projectId: "removed",
    storageBucket: "removed",
    messagingSenderId: "removed",
    appId: "removed",
    measurementId: "removed"
  };

  let app;

  if(firebase.apps.length === 0) {
      app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  } else {
      app = firebase.app();
  }

  const db = app.firestore();
  const auth = firebase.auth();

  export { db, auth };
```

And the error i have is

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.apps.length')
(D'

```
Evaluating module://firebase.js.js
  Evaluating module://screens/LoginScreen.js.js
  Evaluating module://App.js.js
  Loading module://App.js`
```

Any help please ? Thanks

Comment: `firebase.apps` is undefined... So trying to read the length property throws the error. Try to change the condition to `if(!firebase.apps)`. --- I am not used to firebase, so just take this as *"something to try"* ;)

Comment: Thanks, @LouysPatriceBessette I tried this but I still has the same error

Comment: Same error? check if `firebase` is defined then : `console.log("firebase is: ", typeof(firebase));`

Comment: Any solution found? Having this error myself...

Answer (score 3):

Change `import * as firebase from "firebase/app";` for `import firebase from "firebase/app";`.

It worked for me after upgrade from v7 to v8.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

import 'firebase/compat/auth';

import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

"firebase": "^9.6.6"

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

to:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
```